# Упаковка стороних exe в python pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

У меня есть приложение на с++ (не моё) с исходниками. Мне нужно запустить его через питон, но упаковать его вместе с python скриптом.(1 exe файл) Для создания exe из питона я использую pyinstaller. Можно ли реализовать такое, или питон на такое не способен?

Comment: Для поиска решения я разделил бы задачу на 2 части: 1) запуск кода на питоне 2) сборка исполняемого файла с помощью pyinstaller. Уверен, что знающие пользователи смогут подсказать, если Вы дополните вопрос такой информацией: а) запустился ли Ваш питоновский код б) при попытке сборки  была ли ошибка и какая именно ошибка появилась.

Comment: @ViktorIlyenko на самом деле проблема не в Питоне. То есть программу на Питоне я собрал, и умею собирать их через pyinstaller но мне нужно как-то через питон запускать программу на плюсах из ресурсов exe файла в который все пакуется. Наверное все-таки это слишком сложно.